# blank value is coming in c# asp.net whereas it is 0.0 in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dbnull

> blank value is coming in c# asp.net whereas it is 0.0 in sql server  i
>   think due to which i am getting `Dbnull` error.
>   screenshot attached.[c# asp.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaiDW.png)[sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGKSN.png)

```
public decimal TotalValue {
    get {

        try {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn, DBNull.Value)) {
                return 0.0;
            } else {
                return Convert.ToDecimal(this(this.tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn));
            }

        } catch (System.InvalidCastException e) {
            throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'TotalValue' in table 'wsm_View_PurchaseOrderList' is DBNull" + ".", e);
        }
    }
    set { this(this.tablewsm_View_PurchaseOrderList.TotalValueColumn) = value; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: no data coming from SP